# exc_bad_access on appdelegate before shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier

Tags: ios, swift, exc-bad-access

I have a segue from clicking a button to a view controller. In the swift class for the view controller containing the button I have:

```
override func shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String, sender: AnyObject!) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

When I run the simulator and click the button I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error on the AppDelegate class. This error doesn't occur if I remove the method.

Thanks

Comment: I had a weird issue with segue identifiers in a recent beta, for a project created with an older version. Does your segue have an identifier set in Interface Builder? Try adding/changing/otherwise re-setting it and recompiling.

Comment: I have the same issue if identifier=""

Answer (score 3):

You **must** assign Identifer for your segue

If you connect a segue from the button directly:

1. In storyboard choose your segue
2. In Attributes Inspector assign Identifer

If you use the link to the icon for the exit on your controller for unwind action:

1. In document outline choose Unwind Segue to Scene
2. and also assign Identifer In Attributes Inspector

If Identifer not specified, **shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier** will not work

Comment: I do not understand why this has not been marked as answer. I was having this same problem and just naming the segue worked for me. Thanks Eugene!